# Add text after input field with form api (field-suffix)

Tags: 7, forms

I'm creating a form with a textfield. After the input field I'd like to have some text. Like this:

```
Label *
|________| some text
Field description
```

The code I use is:

```
$form['a_textfield'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('A Label'),
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 15,
    '#description' => t('A Field description'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Is there a way do add "some text" after the input field in this way? Do I have do output the HTML code manually via #markup? Is there some way to do this via form alter? Or a theming function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [`#field_suffix`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#field_suffix) property for exactly that:

> Text or code that is placed directly after a textfield. This can be used to add a unit to a textfield.

For example:

```
$form['a_textfield'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('A Label'),
  '#size' => 10,
  '#maxlength' => 15,
  '#description' => t('A Field description'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#field_suffix' => 'Suffix'
);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for me. Is there any way to remove the extra span coming "<span class="field-suffix"><span class="checkmark"></span></span>"